# Insert element at index and Delete element by value in a Array

Tags: go

What is the fastest way to insert an element at the index and Delete an element by value in a large Array? I can loop over the contents of the array (find the location and then shift all the elements) but it will give complexity of o(n).

Is there a built-in that can help shift the elements in an array/slice? or if there is another data structure that can help?

Comment: Not built into the language. Someone may have created some sort of library to provide some or all of that functionality.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/. As customary for linked lists doesn't allow random access, though.

Comment: Basically this is an "Exceptional Bad Idea" (TM) anyway. One of the main advantages of Go is its static typing.

Comment: It is also questionable whether List is a strong data type in Python as you say. To me it seems rather weakly typed if it allows anything inside.

Answer (score 2):

> [Is there a] Go[...] datatype similar to List in Python [?]

No, there is not.